# How do I call a JavaScript function from within Objective-C in a Phonegap app for iPhone?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, cordova

I created a Phonegap app for iPhone which works well so far.

Now I need to call a JavaScript function from within my Objective-C code.

How do I do this? I already tried the following but it won't work:

In **AppDelegate.m** method **"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"**:

```
[self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"test()"];
```

In my **JavaScript** file:

```
function test(){
    alert("called");
}
```

**Result:** Nothing happens. What's wrong?

Comment: try these
[self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"test();"];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try implementing (if it isn't already) one of the UIWebView delegate methods. The WebView may not be fully initialised by the end of the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

In the .m file for your viewcontroller, add:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
         [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"test()"];
   }
```

EDIT: the webViewDidFinishLoad delegate method may actually work better for this.

Comment: Jep, that was the problem. webView wasn't ready yet when I did the Javascript call - thanks!